# nginx reverse proxy "ip address shows"

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, nginx, spring-security, reverse-proxy

I have nginx serving the `example.com` website on my server. The same server is running a tomcat installation serving the `http://server_ip:8080/app` webapp (which is a spring MVC webapp, secured with Spring Security).

I want to be able to access the tomcat webapp using the `http://app.example.com` address. What I did is configure nginx as a reverse proxy as follows (in the `app.example.com` configuration file under `sites-enabled`):

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     app.example.com;
  root            /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app;


  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://server_ip:8080/;
  }
}
```

where `server_ip` is the IPv4 address of my server.

Also, in the `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml` file I added:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="" docBase="app">
         <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
     </Context>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

</Host>
```

so that tomcat is by default sending me to the `app` webapp when I access `http://server_ip:8080` (the `app` webapp is the only thing it is serving anyway).

Now, if I access `http://app.example.com` I get the login page for the `app` webapp alright; however, after logging in, the URL field of the browser is showing `http://server_ip:8080` instead of `http://app.example.com`, as I would expect.

Anybody has a hint of what is causing this? All guides I found on the net seem to suggest a configuration like the one I have. I would love if someone could confirm if the configuration is ok, because that may point to a cause other than server config (may be related to the way spring security redirects after login).

Thanks.

Comment: You missed `proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot. Care to put your comment in an answer so I can upvote you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

And actually, I don't see any reason to have `X-Forwarded-Host` and `X-Forwarded-Server` headers.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I admit those two are there because the example I found on the web had them :-P. I'll look deeper in the docs to understand what they do (and remove them if not needed).